# Extjs4 with DWRproxy

Tags: extjs, proxy, extjs4, dwr

I use dwrproxy.js from https://code.google.com/p/extjs4dwr and I create a grid with store

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.define('Record', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields : [
            {name: 'clientName'},
            {name: 'type'}
        ],
        proxy : {
            type: 'dwr',
            dwrFunction : Manager.getList,

            reader : {
               type: 'json',
               root: 'data',
               totalProperty: 'count'
           }
        }
    })

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        requires : ['Ext.ux.DwrProxy'],
        model: 'Record'

    });

    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store : store,
        columns: [
            {header: "clientName", width: 260, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'clientName'},
            {header: "type", width: 260, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'type'}
        ],
        title:'Test view',
        renderTo: 'container'
    });


    store.load();
});
```

`Manager.getList` looks

```
  Manager.getList = function(p0, p1, callback) {
     dwr.engine._execute(Manager._path, 'Manager', 'getList', p0, p1, callback);
  }
```

And I receive data in dwr

```
throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';
//#DWR-INSERT
//#DWR-REPLY
var s0=[];var s2={};var s3={};
s2.clientName='Client1';s2.type='Type1';
s3.clientName='Client2';s3.type='Type2';
s1.descendingOrder=true;s1.pageNo=null;s1.pageSize=1;s1.sortField="lastEditTime";
dwr.engine._remoteHandleCallback('1','0',{data:s0,dataSize:2,fromIndex:0,fromIndexDisp:1,gridState:s1,metaData:null,moreData:null,pageNo:0,pageNumber:1});
```

Everything look good, but grid is still have a 'loading' status and there are no view. 
Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about DWR, but by mocking your code we can see that the callback is passed as the first argument to your `getList()` method, but it expects it as the third argument.

The position of the callback argument will in fact depend on the `dwrParams` config option of the proxy:

```
// adding parameters if there are defined any in proxy
// configuration
if (typeof (me.dwrParams) === 'object') {
    dwrParams = dwrParams.concat(me.dwrParams);
}
```

So, what you need to do is configure your params in the proxy:

```
    proxy : {
        type: 'dwr',
        dwrFunction : Manager.getList,

        // use params that are sensible for your function
        dwrParams: [1,2],

        // ... your reader config
    }
```

Or I guess that would probably makes more sense to set these before loading your store instead:

```
store.proxy.dwrParams = [1,2];
store.load();
```

If you want to avoid this hackish way, you can override the proxy's code. For example, if you replace these lines (starting line 71 in my version):

```
// adding parameters if there are defined any in proxy
// configuration
if (typeof (me.dwrParams) === 'object') {
    dwrParams = dwrParams.concat(me.dwrParams);
}
```

By these:

```
// adding parameters if there are defined any in proxy
// configuration
var loadParams = operation.dwrParams || me.dwrParams;
if (typeof (loadParams) === 'object') {
    dwrParams = dwrParams.concat(loadParams);
}
```

You could then load your store in a clean way:

```
store.load({
    dwrParams: [3,4]
});
```

As a side note, I saw an error in the DwrProxy's code. A bit further in the same function, there is this code that uses a `dwrParams0` variable that does not exist:

```
case 'read':
    me.dwrFunction.read.apply(null, dwrParams0);
    break;
```

I guess the author probably meant `dwrParams[0]`. You may want to fix this if you ever need to use different functions for the different CRUD operation as in the [DwrProxy example](https://code.google.com/p/extjs4dwr/wiki/HowToUse).

Comment: Thank's a lot for your reply @rixo. I updated the code, but, I have an error on line `dwrParams.push({........errorHandler : function (message) { if(console != undefined) { console.log(message);`

Comment: Why we put into dwrParams 1 and 2?

Comment: You are not required to change the proxy's code, it was just a suggestion for a cleaner code.

Comment: For your code to work, you just need to set your dwrFunction parameters before loading the store: `store.proxy.dwrParams = [1,2];` before `store.load();`


The 1 and 2 here are just example values. You have to replace them with the value of the parameters (p0, and p1 in your code) you want to pass to your Manager.getList method.